# Having a hard time activating my command flag in my c++ program

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, flags

Doing a project assignment and I can not seem to get my command flag working.  Been looking for help online but can not find much on this subject.  My teacher never explained what this is or how to do it so I am just doing things based on what I found online.  Any solution or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
            {
                ifstream file1(argv[i]);
                string arg1 = argv[i];
                int counter = 0;
                int counter2 = 0;
                string longest, word;
                char letter;
                vector<string> arrayWord, numString;
                vector<int> largestNum;
                stringstream ss;

             if(file1.is_open() == false)
               {
                 cout << "File Not Found\n";
                 continue;
               }
             else if (arg1 == "c")
               {
                    while (!file1.eof())
                    {
                        letter = file1.get();

                        if(letter != ' ')
                        {
                            word = word + letter;
                            letter = file1.get();
                            counter++;
                        }
                        else if (letter == ' ')
                        {
                            arrayWord[counter2] = word;
                            largestNum[counter2] = counter;
                            ss << largestNum[counter2];

                            numString[counter2] = ss.str();

                            counter2++;
                            word.clear();
                        }
                    }
                    longest = arrayWord[0];
                    for (int i = 0; i <= counter2; i++)
                    {
                        if (largestNum[counter2] < largestNum[counter2 + 1])
                        {
                            longest = arrayWord[counter2 + 1] + "(" + numString[counter2 + 1];
                        }
                        else if (largestNum[counter2] == largestNum[counter2 + 1])
                        {
                            longest = longest + "(" + (numString[counter2 + 1]) + ", " + arrayWord[counter2 + 1] + "(" + numString[counter2 + 1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            longest = arrayWord[counter2] + "(" + numString[counter2];
                        }
                    }
                    cout << longest << endl;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Program is running with an invalid command" << endl;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Any solution or explanation...* for what?

Comment: I can not get my command flag working and I am hoping someone can explain to why it is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to run the same functionality against each item on the command line.

I would strongly recommend splitting your actual functionality into a separate function (`process_file`), then you can loop through the arguments and run your functionality.

**NOTE:** we are starting from `argv[1]` because `argv[0]` is whatever the user typed on the command line to get your program. This is usually something like `./my-program` assuming the user typed `./my-program file1.txt file2.txt`

The below example will run your functionality on each file.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        printf("Processing \"%s\":\n", argv[i]);
        process_file(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what that means like what do you mean functionality?  My school uses java but we are required this course from another school which uses c++ so I am very unfamiliar with the language and my teacher did not explain these command flags or even mentioned them in class at all.  I am sorry if I sound like an idiot but I am truly at wit's end with this.

Comment: @HanKuSung this is meant as the solution to the question of `how do i use positional arguments`. so in the example above. `void process_file(char * filename)` would be a function you write to open the file and do all the processing on that file that you show above.

Comment: @HanKuSung Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and yes I think so.  I was unable to hand in the assignment in time but I think I can get the next one in properly.  Thank you.